# HUD, Unity Launcher and menu bar not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz

The menu bar doesn't work with any application and the unity launcher doesn't respond. In addition, I can't close a window with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (it works with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, though). But it gets weirder. If I start a session with a guest user, everything works just fine.

I've tried what they say here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but without success. The Compiz settings manager installs and runs fine, but I noticed that there is no checkbox next to the Unity plugin icon.

Any idea what this can be and, above all, how can it be solved? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: As suggested by dadexix86, I tried to reset Unity with the terminal, without success. In the picture is the error message I got (sorry for the potato quality, but the screen capture isn't working, either) [image]

Comment: Try resetting Unity with `unity --reset`

Comment: Am I right to assume that I have to open a terminal and type that command? Do I need sudo, too?

Comment: Either you do it in the terminal, or in the tty2 (accessible with Ctrl+Alt+F2). And no, you do not need sudo :)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, didn't work. See above

Comment: Above... Where? In the question that you posted that had a lot answers?

Comment: I did not see it as a suggested solution. Can you please link the answer that provides it? And can you also please say exactly which of those many solutions did you try?

Comment: Sorry, just finished editing. Should've answered to your comment after that

Comment: You don't have the title bar there. Did it disappear after you used my command or it was not there even before?

Comment: Can you try to just launch `unity` and post the answer?

Comment: it was never there. title bars, menu bars, everything is gone.  I will try to launch unity from the terminal now, and will report

Comment: Ok, so the problem is different from what you say in the question! The problem is not that the menu doesn't work or that the launcher does not respond. The problem is that they are not there! When did the problem change? After you typed which command?

Comment: the message I get is the same in the first part of the pic I uploaded above "... is outside of valid range"

Comment: That's just a warning, not an error. Do you get the same error as in the second part of the image?

Comment: The problem was always that. As I describe in the question. When you log in as the main user, the menu bars and the Unity launcher don't show up. The HUD doesn't work when I press Alt, Unity launcher doesn't appear when I press Super. Also, Alt+F4 doesn't work, but Ctrl+Q does. If I open a session as a guest user, there is no problem.

Comment: That's not what you described there (if something does not respond it means that it is there and when you click on it nothing happens, for the launcher this means clicking on an icon and no action follows. But in your case the launcher is not even there), but no problem let's go on! Try following the answer below

Comment: Almost the same: instead of "unable to find interface type 3 on 0x943f370" i get "unable to find interface type 3 on 0x880a370", and instead of "process 4211", I get "process 2435". The rest is the same

Comment: Try to remove the cache as described below or in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1013266/29595

Comment: Didn't work.  I tried removing the cache following the instructions of the linked answer. When I perform the setsid unity command, I get basically the same message as before, and when I start the session after rebooting, nothing has changed.

Comment: Ok, so far which of the answers in the linked discussion did you try to follow?

Comment: I tried two: the one that resets conpizconfig and the one right above, with the TTY.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem on vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 after a recent update.  I just renamed the .cache folder so it would make a new one.  This is a bit of a sledgehammer approach, but it worked for me.